# How to create a snapshot of current ubuntu installed programs, so that I can copy it to another fresh installation of ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, snapshot

I have some installed programs on Ubuntu on my remote server (which I have root access to it). Now I need to install a fresh Ubuntu on some other machine/server, and I don't want to go through installing all these programs and dependencies again(mysql, rails, rvm, nginx, etc...). So is there a way to capture current state of Ubuntu programs and configurations and copy it to **another** Ubuntu installation ?

Comment: An easy question if you just google http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1881926

Comment: Thanks for the link, but this works with local machine, however I couldn't do it with my remote server (which I have root access on it), so any way to do this with remote server without GUI ? Just from terminal?

Comment: The link from ubuntuforums.org in the above comment has the same `dpkg` command as your answer... A search of stackexchange would have found this too http://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found this link which exactly solves my problem :)

http://eggsonbread.com/2010/01/28/move-ubuntu-to-another-computer-in-3-simple-steps/

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question.  Super User's purpose is to build a knowledge base here rather than a collection of links to answers elsewhere; external links often break, in which case the answer would not be useful.  Please include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution and reference.  Just a heads up, link-only answers tend to attract downvotes and are often deleted.  BTW, in another day, you will be able to accept your answer to indicate that the problem has been solved.

Comment: This method, using `dpkg --get-selections` will list every single package installed, default ones, libraries, everything. They may not match exactly a freshly installed system, and forcibly downgrading packages could be unpredictable at best